# Working with jquerytypeahead does not display list

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

Good morning guys, I'm trying to implement this autocomplete.  I created my method returning a json!

```
[{Name: "Test Group 1"}, {name: "Test Group 2"}, {name: "Test Group 3"}]
```

My JS looks like this:

```
$.typeahead({
        input: "#Grupo",
        source: {
            ajax: function () {
                return {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Home/GetDados',
                    data: { q: '{{query}}' },
                    callback: {
                        done: function (data) {
                            return data.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        minLength: 3,
        order: "asc",
        dynamic: true
    });
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Grupo: </label>
        <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
                <span class="typeahead__query">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Grupo, new { @type = "search", @autocomplete = "off", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Selecione ou insira uma nova pessoa", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "obrigatório" })
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when typing something, in the console it displays the results but does not display the list for the user to select. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what's the CSS like for class typeahead_query? spans aren't block level by default.. Maybe that is it. Quick hack would be to try div in place of span...

Comment: Is the default plugin css: http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

I tried with div too and not list